# How to resolve issue with outdated dc.js typings version?

Tags: d3.js, typescript, dc.js, crossfilter, typescript-typings

I'm trying to do a prototype using dcjs, d3, crossfilter with typescript and jspm. The problem that I have is that typings available for d3 is at version 4.2.38 but dcjs typings is at version 0.0.19 which is dependent on d3 version 3.5.36. Therefore, when I tsc compile I get errors like this:

> ```
> node_modules/@types/dc/index.d.ts(104,32): error TS2314: Generic type 'Selection<GElement, Datum, PElement, PDatum>' requires 4 type argument(s).
> node_modules/@types/dc/index.d.ts(104,80): error TS2314: Generic type 'Selection<GElement, Datum, PElement, PDatum>' requires 4 type argument(s).
> node_modules/@types/dc/index.d.ts(130,26): error TS2314: Generic type 'Selection<GElement, Datum, PElement, PDatum>' requires 4 type argument(s).
> node_modules/@types/dc/index.d.ts(130,53): error TS2314: Generic type 'Selection<GElement, Datum, PElement, PDatum>' requires 4 type argument(s).
> node_modules/@types/dc/index.d.ts(131,29): error TS2314: Generic type 'Selection<GElement, Datum, PElement, PDatum>' requires 4 type argument(s).
> node_modules/@types/dc/index.d.ts(131,56): error TS2314: Generic type 'Selection<GElement, Datum, PElement, PDatum>' requires 4 type argument(s).
> node_modules/@types/dc/index.d.ts(132,39): error TS2314: Generic type 'Selection<GElement, Datum, PElement, PDatum>' requires 4 type argument(s).
> node_modules/@types/dc/index.d.ts(132,87): error TS2314: Generic type 'Selection<GElement, Datum, PElement, PDatum>' requires 4 type argument(s).
> node_modules/@types/dc/index.d.ts(134,22): error TS2314: Generic type 'Selection<GElement, Datum, PElement, PDatum>' requires 4 type argument(s).
> node_modules/@types/dc/index.d.ts(134,41): error TS2314: Generic type 'Selection<GElement, Datum, PElement, PDatum>' requires 4 type argument(s).
> node_modules/@types/dc/index.d.ts(192,20): error TS2314: Generic type 'Selection<GElement, Datum, PElement, PDatum>' requires 4 type argument(s).
> node_modules/@types/dc/index.d.ts(194,23): error TS2314: Generic type 'Selection<GElement, Datum, PElement, PDatum>' requires 4 type argument(s).
> node_modules/@types/dc/index.d.ts(197,27): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/meisam/code-archive/ts-proto/node_modules/@types/d3/index"' has no exported member 'svg'.
> node_modules/@types/dc/index.d.ts(206,27): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/meisam/code-archive/ts-proto/node_modules/@types/d3/index"' has no exported member 'svg'.
> node_modules/@types/dc/index.d.ts(227,33): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/meisam/code-archive/ts-proto/node_modules/@types/d3/index"' has no exported member 'layout'.
> node_modules/@types/dc/index.d.ts(314,32): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/meisam/code-archive/ts-proto/node_modules/@types/d3/index"' has no exported member 'svg'.
> node_modules/@types/dc/index.d.ts(334,32): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/meisam/code-archive/ts-proto/node_modules/@types/d3/index"' has no exported member 'geo'.
> node_modules/@types/dc/index.d.ts(336,23): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/meisam/code-archive/ts-proto/node_modules/@types/d3/index"' has no exported member 'geo'.
> node_modules/@types/dc/index.d.ts(347,27): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/meisam/code-archive/ts-proto/node_modules/@types/d3/index"' has no exported member 'svg'.
> node_modules/@types/dc/index.d.ts(358,28): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/meisam/code-archive/ts-proto/node_modules/@types/d3/index"' has no exported member 'svg'.
> node_modules/@types/dc/index.d.ts(412,32): error TS2314: Generic type 'Selection<GElement, Datum, PElement, PDatum>' requires 4 type argument(s).
> node_modules/@types/dc/index.d.ts(412,83): error TS2314: Generic type 'Selection<GElement, Datum, PElement, PDatum>' requires 4 type argument(s).
> ```

Is there a solution to this?

Also as a general question if type definition for a certain javascript package is not available is there a way to generate them?

Comment: I think the typings version correspond to the library versions. So you'll need to use the d3 3.x typings.

Comment: @EthanJewett are you suggesting that I have to use an older version of d3 to use dc?

Comment: That's right. D.C.js uses d3v3 (the 3.x versions).

Comment: Thanks Ethan. You answered my question!